# Can we set HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost to some 10 ? in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, http, nsurlsession

in my ios Project I have to improve the upload data performance hence I am uploading the data async in multiple threads, However `[HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost][1]`  is  4 by default in iOS

As I am using the shared session, i believe Its creating only 4 connections and which is making my threads to wait until the connection is available, 
**Can I set HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost to some 10 or to some max value ?** 
Is that ok if we have 10 simultaneous connections to the same host?

Answer (score 1):

You may get request timeout error if system reduce number of connection. Even if you set `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost` to 10,  a session may use a lower limit.

From [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1407597-httpmaximumconnectionsperhost?language=objc):

> Additionally, depending on your connection to the Internet, a session
>   may use a lower limit than the one you specify.

Comment: what is your suggesting to make sure that urlsession can handle more than 4 simultaneous requests?

Answer (score 0):

In **URLSessionConfiguration** you can set the **HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost**

```
let urlSessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration()
urlSessionConfiguration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 10
let session = URLSession(configuration: urlSessionConfiguration)
```

Comment: I know its a variable and we can set the value , but my question is , is that ok if we have 10 simultaneous connections to the same host?

Comment: It depends Upon your server capacity. But 10 request won't be a problem. You can go up with load test.